# Bitbucket conditional restriciton for branch

Tags: groovy, bitbucket, hook, bitbucket-server

**Team** - We like to enable below mentioned condition in bitbucket server.

**Condition** - Always feature branch should be created from master and not from anything else.

**What we explored**: "**Create branch wizard for bitbucket**" - This don't suit us because of cost constraint.

**Note**: We have enabled script runner. hence looking to use this with groovy script. Or, any best solution for this case.

We are totally new to bitbucket scrip-runner and groovy. We request you to explain clearly where and how to enable this.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788007/bitbucket-groovy-conditional-script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788007/bitbucket-groovy-conditional-script this is related to pull request. Here am looking for restricting branch creation. Both are different requirements. Please help.